# What is the `configs` argument in Kafka's Serializer<T> interface?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Kafka's `Serializer<T>` interface has a `configure` method that takes a Map.
But since kafka-client's KafkaProducer key/value serializer config simply takes the name of a class and no arguments, where does this Map come from ?

https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serializer.html#configure(java.util.Map,boolean)

Answer (score 0):

If you've seen any examples from Confluent Platform's Schema Registry, you might have noticed code like this

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
```

The second property is used by the serializer, passed into the configure method.

You can also put an actual instance of the serializer into the client properties after the configure method has been called

```
Serializer<?> ser = new KafkaAvroSerializer();
ser.configure(...);  // same properties as above, but explicitly those for this serializer 
// props for producer 
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,ser);
```

In Kafka Connect, you will see properties like

```
"key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
```

The second line is a configurable value passed to the converter and its inner (de)serializer